# How can I get items from a list from a specific index?

Tags: dart

How can I get only the items ahead of a specified index in a list? 
Example:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
print(numbers[3..]);
```

Output: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [skip](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Iterable/skip.html) method, to skip a number of elements at the start of a List, for example:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
print(numbers.skip(3)); //Returns an iterable: (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```